Remove Dollar Sign ($) from Magento Inline Edit
I have an inline edit module, and it's working fine, but my price field displays the dollar sign "$" when I click on a record to edit inline. This is annoying because then I need to backspace the dollar sign to remove it each time I want to save, since it is not a number.
I tried both, from within the ProductDataProvider, and as a JS component, but neither are working for me. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
app/code/Vendor/GridInlineEditor/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php:
    <?php
namespace Vendor\GridInlineEditor\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider as MagentoProductDataProvider;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class ProductDataProvider extends MagentoProductDataProvider
{
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $collectionFactory, $addFieldStrategies, $addFilterStrategies, $meta, $data);
        
    $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect(['cost', 'status_watch', 'date_recent', 'band_color']);
}

public function getData()
{
    $data = parent::getData();

    foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {
        if (isset($item['cost'])) {
            $item['cost'] = $this->removeFormatting($item['cost']);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

private function removeFormatting($value)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $value);
}
}

app/code/Vendor/GridInlineEditor/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/price.js:
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (Column, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

return Column.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        this.getFieldHandler = wrapper.wrap(this.getFieldHandler, this._wrapGetFieldHandler.bind(this));
    },

    _wrapGetFieldHandler: function (originalHandler) {
        return function (record) {
            var result = originalHandler.call(this, record);
            if (typeof result === 'object' && result.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
                // Only remove the dollar sign when editing the field inline
                result.value = this.removeDollarSign(result.value);
            }
            return result;
        }.bind(this);
    },

    removeDollarSign: function (value) {
        return value.replace(/^\$/, '');
    }
});
});


After much R&D I got the solution. I got rid of the price.js file and instead am using an inline_edit.phtml for the JS, code is below:


require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/core/app'], function($) {
    
    function cleanAndReenterValue($input) {
        var value = $input.val();
        if (value.includes('$') || value.includes(',') || value.includes(' ')) {
            // Remove dollar sign, commas, and extra spaces
            var cleanedValue = value.replace(/[$,]/g, '').trim();
            
            // Simulate re-entering the value by clearing it and setting it back
            $input.val('');
            $input.val(cleanedValue); 
            console.log('value re-entered');
            
            // Trigger the change and blur events to signal to Magento that it changed
            $input.trigger('change'); 
            $input.trigger('blur'); 
        }
    }
    
    // Automatically clean price and cost fields when any field is clicked
    $(document).on('click', '.data-grid-editable-row', function() {
        
        // Clean price field
        $('input[name="price"]').each(function() {
            cleanAndReenterValue($(this));
        });

        // Clean cost field
        $('input[name="cost"]').each(function() {
            cleanAndReenterValue($(this));
        });
    });

    $(document).on('afterRender', function() {
        $('input[name="price"], input[name="cost"]').each(function() {
            cleanAndReenterValue($(this));
        });
    });
});

I have a "price" and "cost" field, you can get rid of one of them and use whichever is in your code. Then, all you gotta do is create a catalog_product_index.xml file inside the view/adminhtml/layout directory in order to call that script:


<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="VendorName_GridInlineEditor::inline_edit.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>

Hope this helps someone!
